# Google Cloud Platform lists project under "No organization", but it is not correct

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

GCP projects appear to be associated with an organization even though Google's Cloud Console claims otherwise.
This provides a full access backdoor to an external company.

How do we secure our project and verify that it is only our own users who can access it?

Our software platform has been developed by an external company who based it on Google Cloud Platform and Firebase and we have assumed control of the platform and we will be the ones to maintain it going forward.

Our software platform consists of three GCP projects and we have removed access for all users from the external company for security reasons, so that only our own users should be able to access our resources.

However one of the developers from the external company mentioned that the three projects are associated with their organization in GCP and that he has full access to all of our projects even though he's not listed anywhere.

When I view our three GCP projects from within Google's Cloud Console, it says that they belong to "No organization".

I asked him to test it out, because it seemed dubious to me, but he now confirms that he has tested it and that he does in fact have full access to view our Firebase resources for instance - including production user data and so on.

How do I ensure that the only users who have access to our GCP projects are our own users. And if this organization backdoor does in fact exist, am I the only one who thinks that's a blatant security flaw?
I mean we have an external company with full access to our resources and it doesn't seem to show up anywhere, in fact it claims the opposite to be true.

We need our GCP projects to be securely in our own control, how do we achieve that?

Comment: 1) If the OP is correct, you have a security problem, probably caused by the other company NOT understanding Google Cloud IAM. You might be confused and the information in your question could be wrong. You need to contact Google Cloud Platform Support. This link will help you understand the steps to migrate your projects to another org. https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration

Comment: 2) If Google confirms that your project is not part of an organization, then you  have an IAM issue. This means some identity (user, service account, group, domain, etc) has a member entry in the project. Delete them.

Comment: @JohnHanley From his account the projects are associated with their organization. He has confirmed it with a screenshot. However from my account GCP claims that the projects do not belong to an organization.

As a super administrator for the organization, he has a full backdoor access to our projects. Can this really be?
It appears we can't receive any support from Google unless we pay through the nose for it.

Comment: Contact Google for this issue. No, I do not believe they have a backdoor. They have access via either Organizations or IAM. You don't have access due to lack of privilege. Now you need Google to help you as I cannot see your account information, IAM, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when a project I had access to was listed under an Organization of which I did not have sufficient permissions to view. Critically, I was missing the `resourcemanager.organizations.get` permission on the organization.

Because of this, the GCP UI will not show the parent organization (and it won't be selectable from the Resource Selection Dropdown. However, if you run `gcloud projects list --format json` you should be able to see a similar output to below which shows that the project is actually a child of a parent organization.

```
{
    "createTime": "2021-03-10T21:42:15.100Z",
    "lifecycleState": "ACTIVE",
    "name": "Project Name",
    "parent": {
      "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "type": "organization"
    },
    "projectId": "project-id",
    "projectNumber": "XXXXXXXXXX"
  }
```

In your case, it is likely that you don't have `resourcemanager.organizations.get` permissions for the developers external organization.

I would recommend [migrating the project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration) into your organization so that it is migrated away from the external developers org - as a project can only exist in 1 organization at a time